# C++ and UML diagrams

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Let be A and B class such that are which inherit of C class. All are in a file.cpp  together with method main of the Main class. If I want create a instance of the classe A then ...

file.cpp

```
 class C{
 }

 class A : public C{
 }

 class B : public C{
 }
 class Main{
 .
 .
 .
 void main(){
    C *c = new A();
 }
 }
```

Where a diagram UML is

[image]

Now, Suppose I have the same classes but each class in a different file. If I want to instantiate the class A, as above, I would have insert an #include A.h directive in the Main class which would bring up a dependency in my diagram:

My question is: Which case is correct if I wanted to do the same? or I am interpreting wrong the relations UML in C++?

[image]

Comment: In your question, "Which one is the right one if I wanted to do the same? Or I am interpreting wrong the relations UML in C++?", please try to use proper nouns instead of "one" or "right one" or "do the same" because they're vague and/or ambiguous. By being verbose, it helps us to quickly understand what you're trying to find. Could you revise that please? And, could you update the question title to be more specific too please?

Comment: @Juan UML purely depicts relationships between classes and is not based on the physical location of these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should not put code in .h files unless you know what you are doing (see [inline functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-functions.html), mainly used for speed)

Then in main.h, you don't need any reference to A. In main.cpp however, you will need to include A.h. Remember that UML is language agnostic, it is used to draw "who talks to who" rather than "who compiles with who".

More often than not, your c++ compiler will generate an output file (with gcc these are .o files, Visual Studio also does this but transparently) for each cpp file. All output files will then be merged together (most of the time) in your application or library and only then will your function be linked together.

You might also want to take a look at [forward references](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/21527/). It is to tell the compiler (not the linker) that "this class does exist, you might not know about it right now, but I swear to God, it WILL exist in the linker output blob".

In your particular case, I would draw the class diagram like your second example, regardless of whether you use only one or multiple cpp files. Your Main class DOES know about A.

Now imagine that your C class have methods like

```
A* C::createA()
{
    return new A;
}

B* C::createB()
{
    return new B;
}
```

Then your main class would have

```
int main()
{
    C* instance1 = C::createA();
    C* instance2 = C::createB();
}
```

In that case, your main class would lose all intimate knowledge of A and B, conforming to your first diagram. This would of course create more coupling between A, B and C, which brings its own problems but is closer to a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: understand but if I want to model the pattern Chain of Responsability. I will be able to use the first diagram?

Comment: Chain of responsibility usually include some kind of self reference. http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx

Comment: yes, I the the fisrt and second diagram: C class dash point to C class. But my doubt is: I use a first or second diagram?

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question

Comment: sorry, ... yes (Chain of responsibility usually include some kind of self reference) remaind an association in the first and second diagram: C class dash point to C class. But my doubt is: I use a first or second diagram to model a chain of responsability pattern?

Comment: Chain of responsibility doesn't really care about the difference between 1 and 2. Design 1 is usually preferred because of the fewer dependencies, but what ultimately matters is that your software does what you want

Answer (score 1):

<s>You need to use the **composition** relationship to show that `Main` *has-a* instance of `C`.</s>

I have never documented which files need to be included, as it is assumed that if you need functionality of a class that lives in another file, you're probably going to need an include.

**EDIT:** Actually, there is *no* composition, as it seems you `Main` class has a methods called `main()` that creates an instance of the `C` class, and is not a member itself.

Comment: understand, in your answer "need functionality of a class that lives in another file, you're probably going to need an include". Then I would have that create a UML arrow association or not necessarily?

Comment: As with the sentence before that, "I have never documented which files need to be included"

Comment: anybody, based in any rule, please will be able to tell us that include files in C++ going to need dependency relation in its UML diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its required to have the has-a relationships   as in the second diagram because it is implied.

A is-a a C, B is-a C and Main has-a C.

Its more about the structure of your design than the includes in your files.